# No message body reader has been found

Tags: json, spring, dictionary, cxf

I have a REST service which consumes application/json, and takes an argument of a Map.

```
@POST
@Path("/mymethod")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain") 
public Response myMethod(Map<String, Object> myMap)
```

I'd like a request to this service to automatically unmarshal the json string payload into the Map, however when I make a request (with content-type application/json) I get the following error:

`No message body reader has been found for request class Map, ContentType : application/json.`

This is a spring project using cxf 2.4.x. I believe that I need to define the bean that is responsible for unmarshalling the payload, but I'm not sure exactly where/how/who. This project currently uses  jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.x. Can I use a class in that jar or its dependency jackson-core-asl-1.9.x? Thanks.